# Python module script.vis install

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

Really sorry for my novice question.

I am trying to install a module in python for neo4j but I got an error.

here is the import :

```
from scripts.vis import vis_network
from scripts.vis import draw
```

Here is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

I have tried "pip install scripts"

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install this script? `pip install`?

Comment: I have tried pip install script but it is not working

Comment: It is for neo4j

Comment: I get the module from this code  http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/twitter.html

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError` simply means the Python interpreter couldn't find the module. I suggest that you read about python modules and packaging [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

I have looked at the source code you pointed to and it works perfectly fine. I suspect your paths are not well set up.

Make sure that in you are running importing `scripts.vis` in `app.py`, the directory structure looks like this:

```
./scripts
    ./scripts/__init__.py
    ./scripts/vis.py
    ....
./app.py #in app.py, you can import as 'from scripts.vis import x'
```

Here's what it looks on my system:

[image]

`app.py` is successfully able to make the import from `vis` sub-module. You can use a IPython notebook, that should work fine too.

Comment: please I cannot make it . can you show me an example .

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: I've updated my answer. Yes, as long as you maintain the directory hierarchy, it works in IPynb as well.

Comment: I have tried :  from vis import draw but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize the graph in the python environment (Jupyter), you can try using `neo4jupyter` library. Here you will use `neo4jupyter.draw` to visualize the graph.

Install `!pip install neo4jupyter`

For example:

```
import neo4jupyter
neo4jupyter.init_notebook_mode()

from py2neo import Node

nicole = Node("Person", name="Nicole", age=24)
drew = Node("Person", name="Drew", age=20)

graph.create(nicole | drew)

options = {"Person": "name"}
neo4jupyter.draw(graph, options)
```

You may find this useful:

https://github.com/merqurio/neo4jupyter

https://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/hello-world.html